# How can I manage different database build reference paths between TFS and my local machine?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, database-project

I have two database projects DB_A and DB_B. Project DB_A references DB_B.

I added a database reference by pointing to DB_B.dbschema at

```
C:\SourceParent\DB Projects\DB_B\sql\debug\DB_B.dbschema
```

When I build project DB_A on my local machine it works fine.

Now I want to build this on my TFS build server, but I get the following error

```
File D:\Builds\SourceParent\Build_Name\DB_B\sql\debug\DB_B.dbschema does not exist
```

I have a build for DB_B on my build server, but it's at a different path (the build definition doesn't necessarily match the project name).

I think I could add a build event in my build definition to copy the .dbschema file to the correct location on the server, but I'd rather not do this. (This would require a special build template for each build definition.)

Is there some way I can make the TFS build point to a different location? Or some other nice way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating an environment variable `$(DB_SCHEMAS)` pointing to a directory on my machine (e.g. `C:\dbschemas`).

Then I added a post build event in project DB_B to copy DB_B.dbschema to `$(DB_SCHEMAS)`.

I then added a database reference in project DB_A pointing to `$(DB_SCHEMAS)\DB_B.dbschema`. Note that Visual Studio will add this reference using a relative path. To fix this, I unloaded the project in Solution Explorer, and edited the hint path to use the `$(DB_SCHEMAS)` environment variable.

Now I just added this environment variable on the TFS server and it will work as expected. Building project DB_B copies its .dbschema file to `$(DB_SCHEMAS)` (wherever that may be) and then building project DB_A references this scheme.

The only downside is that my teammates all have to add this environment variable on their machines as well, otherwise they can't build locally.